# an error occurred while running subprocess

Tags: error-handling

I am developing an application in ionic 5 and I encounter an error when I run the command: ionic cordova platform add android.
Here is the error message: [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova-res. Can anyone help me?

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.0 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.12
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.12
@angular/cli                  : 9.1.12
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : browser 6.0.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 8 other plugins)